# Using international accents in the whole document

Tags: accents, input-encodings

So I am attempting to write a document in Estonian language.
Currently what I do to get characters like `Ä` appear at all, is use this syntax:

```
\"{chracter_I_want_with_dots•}
```

But I am going to write a lot of text that is going to use many characters with dots and other kinds of symbols on top of the characters.

How can I use these characters on the whole document without writing this kind of syntax on every Estonian character?

Comment: I am using TexMaker to write my document. Looking around it's settings it seems that it allready has LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX in it. But how do I make it the default for the whole document?

Comment: You don't need xelatex or lualatex to be able to handle input like "Äöü". They work with pdflatex too. Simply add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` (assuming that your file is utf8 encoded).

Comment: Could you add this as an answer? Got the problem solved thanks to you!